# php isset function for xor operation

Tags: php

```
if($line_of_text['EMPDesignation3'] == '' ^ $line_of_text['EmpName3'] == '') {
                        $error_status['success_msg'] = "emp designation3 and emp name3 not empty";
                        $error_status['status'] = 0;
                        return $error_status;
                    }
```

it shows error Notice: Undefined index: EMPDesignation3 in

Comment: Yes, that variable hasn't such index. Self-explanatory.

Comment: Why you don't use `isset($line_of_text['EMPDesignation3'])` function

Comment: ok , will do @BadshahSahib , because i did xor operation , thats why .

Comment: @karthickeyan check my answer for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for isset with xor operator:

```
 if(isset($line_of_text['EMPDesignation3']) ^ isset($line_of_text['EmpName3'])) {
    $error_status['success_msg'] = "emp designation3 and emp name3 not empty";
    $error_status['status'] = 0;
    return $error_status;
    }
```